# How to delete mac catalyst app data in big sur?

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur

I updated my app so it stopped working, in simulator you just erase data.
In mac catalina you have to delete folder from library/container/
But in big sur container folder is empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To delete Mac catalyst app data ~/Library/Containers/ should indeed contain the folder for your catalyst app - so deleting this folder is just like deleting the app from the simulator in iOS.